# Downgrade UIImage quality to max bytes

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uikit, core-graphics

I have an application where I require a given `UIImage` to be **300x300px** in physical size and less than **500kb** in file size.

The image is taken from the device's photo library and resized to 300x300px.

In most cases the resulting photo is less than 500kb, but depending on the original image (such as resolution) it may be larger.

I do not want to downsize the image further, as I require it to be exactly 300px in its largest dimension.

How can I downgrade the quality on those images to a point where they are less than 500kb in file size (PNG representation)?

Comment: It might help to convert to JPG with some compression and then back to PNG. But PNG is lossless. The only way to make a PNG smaller (for a given pixel size) is for the image to have less detail.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for your comment! So there is no way for me to simply downgrade the quality/ lower the file size in some other way, apart from converting to a lossy format such as JPG?

Comment: There might be a filter or something you could apply to the image that will downgrade the quality. But that's not really much different from converting to/from JPG. Either way you need to lose picture detail to lower the final image size.

Comment: @rmaddy one of the problems of converting to JPG is the lack of support for transparency. Would you mind elaborating on one of these filters that I might be able to apply for the same result?

Comment: I'm not up on image processing and available filters. That's why I said "their might be".